# I see 'my orders' list only like admin, how to male it visible for all customers?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I've created a new tab in myaccount, where all customers have to see all their orders. It's custom, because the design is very not similar to default orders table.
Like admin I see all my orders. But when I try to register like a common user and make test-orders, the tab is empty. So orders display only if current user=admin. How to fix that moment?

```
/**
 * 1. Register new endpoint slug to use for My Account page
 */

/**
 * @important-note  Resave Permalinks or it will give 404 error
 */
function ts_custom_add_my_purchases_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'my_purchases', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}
  
add_action( 'init', 'ts_custom_add_my_purchases_endpoint' );
  
  
/**
 * 2. Add new query var
 */
  
function ts_custom_my_purchases_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'my_purchases';
    return $vars;
}
  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_query_vars', 'ts_custom_my_purchases_query_vars', 0 );
  
  
/**
 * 3. Insert the new endpoint into the My Account menu
 */
  
function ts_custom_add_my_purchases_link_my_account( $items ) {
    $items['my_purchases'] = 'My purchases';
    return $items;
}
  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'ts_custom_add_my_purchases_link_my_account' );
  
  
/**
 * 4. Add content to the new endpoint
 */
  
function ts_custom_my_purchases_content() {?>
    <section class="order">
<?php 
$orders = wc_get_orders( array(
  'numberposts' => -1,  
   'orderby' => 'date',
   'order' => 'DESC',  
   'author' => get_current_user_id(),
) );


//* Loop through each WC_Order object
foreach( $orders as $order ){?>
    <div class="order-wrapper product d-flex col-12">
        <?php 
        $order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data
        $order_id = $order_data['id'];
        $order_currency = $order_data['currency'];
        $order_status = $order_data['status']; ?>
        <div class="order-number">#<?php echo  $order_id;?></div>         
        <div class="order-inner">
            <div class="order-inner-top">
                <?php    
                foreach ($order->get_items() as $key => $lineItem) {
                $product_id = $lineItem['product_id'];
                $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
               
                $item_meta_data = $lineItem->get_meta_data();
                $colormeta = $lineItem->get_meta( 'pa_color', true );
                $sizemeta = $lineItem->get_meta( 'pa_size', true ); 
                echo '<div class="order-inner-top-inner"><div class="order-slider-inner"> <div class="order-inner-left"><div class="order-image">' . $product->get_image(['322', '304']) . '</div></div>';  
                echo '<div class="order-inner-right"><div class="order-info-item order-info-item-name">' . $lineItem['name'] . '</div><div class="order-info-item order-info-item "><span class="order-price">' .  $lineItem['total'] . ' '  . $order_currency  .   '</span></div><div class="order-item-quantity"> '. ' Quantity: ' . $lineItem['qty'] . '</div>';
                echo '<div class="order-item-metas">' . $colormeta . ' , ' . $sizemeta . '</div>';
                echo '</div></div></div>';}  ?>
          </div>          
          
          <div class="order-inner-bottom">
               <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button class="order-total"><?php echo get_theme_mod('orders_total_button');?></button> 
              </div>
              <div class="totals-toggle">
                  <div class="order-info-item bottom"> <span>Total Price:</span><span class="order-total-price"> <?php echo $order->get_total() . '  ' . $order_currency; ?></span></div>       
                  <div class="order-info-item bottom"> <span>Total Quantity:</span> <?php echo  $order->get_item_count(); ?> item(s)</div>         
                  <div class="order-info-item bottom"> <span>Status:</span> <?php echo $order_status;?></div>
                  <div class="order-info-item bottom"> <span>Order Date: </span> <?php echo $order->order_date; ?></div>
                </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
       
 </div> 
<?php  }?>

</section>

 <?php  
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_my_purchases_endpoint', 'ts_custom_my_purchases_content' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't see the orders being a non-admin user, because in the wc_get_orders args you specify that you want to get orders where the author is a current user.

In WooCommerce, users that made orders are not authors of the orders. If you want to get a current user's orders, you have to rewrite your wc_get-orders calling like this:

```php
$orders = wc_get_orders( array(
  'numberposts' => -1,  
   'orderby' => 'date',
   'order' => 'DESC',  
   'customer_id' => get_current_user_id(),
) );
```

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't help, still the same

Comment: helped. polylang confused me. thatk you! where can I read all this parameters? I need pagination for example.

Comment: @libertarian check this [link](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query)